# Unable to load class 'org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.google.common.collect.Lists'

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have imported project in my Android Studio and I encounter this error,

- Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
  org/gradle/internal/impldep/com/google/common/collect/Lists
- Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  org.gradle.internal.impldep.com.google.common.collect.Lists

this is my `dependencies`

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1'  // From node_modules

implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'

implementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre")

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
  exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
}

if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}

}
```

[image]

I already saw this question [No Class Found: com.google.common.collect.Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007629/no-class-found-com-google-common-collect-lists) but when i tried to add the https://github.com/google/guava the error still exist

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")
        compile "com.google.guava:guava:16+"
        compile  "junit:junit:4.10"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: my only concern is this *Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/impldep/com/google/common/collect/Lists* @MartinZeitler

Comment: @Josh [Check the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287822/gradle-error-package-com-google-common-collect-does-not-exist). You might find your answer here.

Comment: @Istiak I've tried to add this *implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'* in my dependencies but the error still exist

Comment: Is it really that had to understand that this is a Gradle issue and not a Java issue? If any dependencies would matter than it would be the `buildscript.dependencies` ...or it may be some corrupted Gradle plugin. That would at least explain why none of these approaches could ever make a difference.

Comment: @MartinZeitler please check my updated question,

Comment: Try updating / re-downloading that `guava` plugin and rebuild those local repositories. Or try to "invalidate caches and restart"... maybe even manually delete all cache directories. I'm almost certain it has something to do with that (depending where this broken dependency comes from). I mean, I can't really reproduce the issue and am in a hurry ...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me. Android Studio completely buggered. Invalidate/reinstall/new project. Still buggered. Deleted .gradle directory (Linux). That fixed it. No idea of the initiating event. Filed a bug.